# CRM 2013 - CRMAppPool identity

Tags: iis, dynamics-crm

I was reading about the IIS CRMAppPool and found this link:

https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/dynamicscrmtipoftheday/archive/2014/05/13/tip-133-do-not-add-crm-application-pool-account-as-a-user

My question is, if you can´t use the CRMAppPool identity as a user, how do you push data into the CRM server without the mentioned risk when my organization has the load balancing front-end configuration (app pool identity as CRM user)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you need the appPool identity as a user to load data in a load balanced CRM?

Comment: Because I have a custom WCF service hosted in the same server that pushes data to the CRM and I´m not sure if it´s possible to have an identity which is not a user in CRM. Then how does the CRM know who is the caller if it´s not identified in the CRM?

Comment: Can you use Another account for the WCF service to connect to the CRM??